# Azure Table Service REST API - Create Table

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to create a table using this operation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135729.aspx

with a json request body. However, all my efforts are rejected with the following response:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>JsonFormatNotSupported</code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">JSON format is not supported.
RequestId:41192a52-0002-007b-5334-b57662000000
Time:2016-05-23T20:48:17.4360778Z</message>
</error>`

The error is mentioned here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179438.aspx

But that's all I can find

Here's what I'm sending:

http://requestb.in/1l9sye21?inspect#1jmf39

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full api call your app is generating. Otherwise, difficult to diagnost.

Comment: Have you set HTTP request header "Content-Type" to "application/json"? Is your request body like: {  "TableName":"mytable" }?

Comment: Yes, please see the request bin link

Comment: Didn't you replace `accountname` with the actual storageaccount name in Authorization or it just names `accountname` ?

Comment: Yes, `accountname` is just for demo, as is `tablename`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need to add the x-ms-version header:

x-ms-version: 2015-04-05

This is required when using Shared Key / Shared Key Lite auth for the Table Service.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894041.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Adam's answer: You need to specify Storage Service Versions in requests when authenticated.

- For **requests using Shared Key or Shared Key Lite**,  you must pass the *x-ms-version* header on the request.
- For **Requests using a Shared Access Signature (SAS)**, the *SignedVersion (sv)* parameter specifies the service version to use to authorize and authenticate.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894041.aspx for more details.

The storage service version used to authenticate with may be incompatible with the version used to process the request, which will lead to some features such as json not available, thus the REST request fails with error `(415) JSON format is not supported.`.

Refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/32 for some information, though it's with SAS rather than SKA.